# How can I add files to specific zip subfolders?

Tags: zip

I need to add files from `/home/user/test/`to existed zip archive like this `try.zip` under specified folder `test`
Folder `test` contains

> newfile1
>   ...
>   newfileN

Archive `try.zip`contains

> folder1/somefile1
>   folder1/somefile2
>   folder2/somefile1
>   folder2/somefile2

And I want get result like this

> folder1/somefile1
>   folder1/somefile2
>   folder2/somefile1
>   folder2/somefile2
>   test/newfile1
>   test/...
>   test/newfileN

But when I exec something like this `zip -ru try.zip /home/user/test/*` in result I get

> folder1/somefile1
>   folder1/somefile2
>   folder2/somefile1
>   folder2/somefile2
>   /home/user/test/newfile1
>   /home/user/test/...
>   /home/user/test/newfileN

So how can I avoid adding `/home/user/` to my zip archive?

Comment: Did you try `cd /home/user && zip -ru folders_containing_your_zip_file/try.zip test/*`?

Comment: @marc yes, this could be used as workaround